# Implementing the Dynamic Payload Length Feature between two nRF24L01+ Modules

Tags: rf

I have two prototype boards, each with a PIC16F690 MCU, SPI connected to an nRF24L01+ Module. I have configured one unit as a PTX and the other as a PRX. I have no problem passing ASCII data from the PTX to the PRX as long as I send the exact number of ASCII characters (from the PTX) as is defined in the RX_PW_P0 register in the PRX device.

I have tried to enable the Enhanced Shockburst (ESB) feature in order to take advantage of the Dynamic Payload Length part of ESB. For the past few weeks, I have been communicating with a NORNIC Semi Technical Engineer trying to get the DPL feature implemented. We tried setting the ESB registers (EN_AA, FEATURE, DYNPD) and associated addresses every which way that we could. He has finally given up and so have I, particularly with the modules that I have purchased.

Now, I have read that there are Real vs Fake nRF24L01+ ICs on the market, and I believe that I have six of the fake ones. My NORDIC contact has told me that I can trust DigiKey and Sparkfun modules. DigiKey doesn’t sell the modules any more and two of the ones that I have came from SparkFun. I would hope that that module would have a Real IC! My question to the group is; does anyone know anything about the Real vs Fake, because my Engineer says that ESB works on their ICs.

Comment: Ask NORDIC which are their official suppliers in your region, and buy from them.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example to send ESP packets in there [product description](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) page

select the download tab and there is an application note nAN24-12 also see the product specification document of nRF24L01 under section 7.3 (page 25) which describe the ES packet format

Comment: I have decided to purchase 2 nRF24L01+ Breakout Boards from SparkFun since I was told by a NORDIC Engineer that they would be a reliable source for the NORDIC device.